# What is the highest possible value for key in couchdb view map?

Tags: indexing, mapreduce, couchdb

Suppose I have composite array for creating a view map. And I want to query all object with the same first key. So I use `?startKey=["someKey"]`

But what is the highest endKey I could use?

I may use `&endKey=["someKey",{}]`. But will `{}` be larger than `{ someOtherKey:{} }` ?

If not then what can I use?

Comment: The quick answer is: **no**, `{any: 'object'}` will be larger than `{}`, but it is difficult to imagine a use case for putting objects in view keys.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While using `{}` was recommended for the longest time, (it was even what I understood until researching for this answer) there is actually a new definitive "highest value".

According to the [latest documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/couchapp/views/collation.html#raw-collation), you should use a string like `"\ufff0"`. This unicode character should find itself at the high end of any pattern for views.